Ray_casting from curve origins doesn't hit any part of the mesh
The terminal prints none, which I guess means the raycast is not hitting anything. To replicate this output. Run the script and navigate to its sidebar in the viewport, select the two nerve curves and the human geometry last, and click on 'Draw Curves On Texture'. Origin locations I verified to be correct, direction axis I verified to be in the correct direction of the mesh, so why does it hit nothing? All because of poorly written API documentation I have to give away my genius code I've worked hundreds of hours on for free. There goes my chance of profiting off of it too! Here's the code: GP_convert

Please provide a minimal working example, ideally just Python code setting up the scene and then trying to raycast and failing, because this way it's readable within the question alone. See: tips on how to ask a question and more tips and if you decide to upload .blend: How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice

Agreed, this question is simply not answerable without access to an external file which is both a security risk and a long term risk since the link may or may not be invalid in the future. Please add a minimal working example. If it can make you feel better, almost nobody makes profits from random blender scripts ;)

Link above is to the test file and in the scripting window a link to your code on your D drive. Nothing lost yet, but nothing to test either. Nice idea you have - maybe (not seeing the code anyway) it has to do with something similar to baking from cage, so MAYBE you can look at scripts that do that?
